# Cordova Mobile App for iOS is not communicating with the server

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, meteor, xcode8

I am doing the Meteor.js tutorial app available at https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app. The app starts on iPhone without a problem but it does not have any server/db data on it. It seems it is not communicating with Meteor server running on my Mac. The iPhone is connected with with Mac via an USB cable.

The Cordova version used by Meteor is 4.3. I have iOS 10.11 on the Mac, iOS 10.2 on the iPhone and Xcode 8.2. The Meteor version is the latest; 1.4.4.2 with all packages up-to-date.

I am appending Xcode runtime log below. What can be the reason? Or, What should I do to understand the root cause of the problem?
P.S: I noticed the log at the end "*Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates*." Does this log give some info about the reason?

```
"*2017-05-24 13:45:24.953911 new-simple-todos[734:211957] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.3.0 is starting.
2017-05-24 13:45:24.954919 new-simple-todos[734:211957] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2017-05-24 13:45:24.968152 new-simple-todos[734:211957]
Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful.
Your application might be rejected by Apple if you store too much data.
For more information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines" at:
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/
To disable web storage backup to iCloud, set the BackupWebStorage preference to "local" in the Cordova config.xml file
2017-05-24 13:45:25.059835 new-simple-todos[734:211957] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2017-05-24 13:45:25.059932 new-simple-todos[734:211957] Using WKWebView
2017-05-24 13:45:25.061030 new-simple-todos[734:211957] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.155985ms
2017-05-24 13:45:25.064366 new-simple-todos[734:211957] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 3.140032ms
2017-05-24 13:45:25.064572 new-simple-todos[734:211957] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.099957ms
2017-05-24 13:45:25.150542 new-simple-todos[734:211957] Serving asset bundle version: 0c8795ba8f3119843203decdfca7177100ddadfe
[INFO] GCDWebServer started on port 12536 and reachable at http://localhost:12536/
2017-05-24 13:45:25.155801 new-simple-todos[734:211957] [CDVTimer][webapplocalserver] 91.096997ms
2017-05-24 13:45:25.167965 new-simple-todos[734:211957] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 12.005985ms
2017-05-24 13:45:25.188704 new-simple-todos[734:211957] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 20.606995ms
2017-05-24 13:45:25.188814 new-simple-todos[734:211957] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 128.023982ms
2017-05-24 13:45:42.008211 new-simple-todos[734:211957] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-05-24 13:45:42.018891 new-simple-todos[734:211957] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2017-05-24 13:45:42.194748 new-simple-todos[734:212176] 0x17014db50 Copy matching assets reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
"Result" => : 29
}
2017-05-24 13:45:42.196590 new-simple-todos[734:212176] 0x17414ea70 Daemon configuration query reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY { count = 2, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
"Dictionary" => { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
"ServerURL" => { count = 3, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
"com.apple.CFURL.magic" => C3853DCC-9776-4114-B6C1-FD9F51944A6D
"com.apple.CFURL.string" => { length = 30, contents = "https://mesu.apple.com/assets/" }
"com.apple.CFURL.base" => : null-object
}
}
"Result" => : 0
}
2017-05-24 13:45:42.197384 new-simple-todos[734:212176] [MobileAssetError:29] Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type com.apple.MobileAsset.TextInput.SpellChecker
[INFO] GCDWebServer stopped
2017-05-24 13:50:54.932894 new-simple-todos[734:211957] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView::
2017-05-24 13:50:54.933009 new-simple-todos[734:211957] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView title: Simple To-do Application
2017-05-24 13:50:54.933064 new-simple-todos[734:211957] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView location: http://localhost:12536/?cdvToken=C875FD73-9549-4F10-8111-371CAB9A0E63-734-000000ADDB99F77C
2017-05-24 13:50:54.933097 new-simple-todos[734:211957] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView reload: 0
[INFO] GCDWebServer started on port 12536 and reachable at http://localhost:12536/
2017-05-24 13:51:12.315192 new-simple-todos[734:211957] Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.*"
```

Comment: Is your phone on the same network as your computer?

Comment: I am connecting it via USB by using Xcode.

Comment: So you think that requests from your iPhone are sent to Meteor server on your computer over the USB? No, that's not true. Make sure that your iPhone and computer are on the same network. If you don't believe me - check this [DOCUMENTATION](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#running-your-app) ("Connecting to Server" chapter)

Comment: @ArtūrsLataks yes you are right. That is the answer, I did not notice that part of the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you iPhone and computer are on the same network. Reference to the Doc [here](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#running-your-app) in "Connect to Server" chapter.